# SettingsPropertyNotFoundException on user's computer

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, application-settings

We have a WinForms application with some settings. It works on the development machine, but crashes on the user's computer with

> SettingsPropertyNotFoundException

when trying to access the settings using `Properties.Settings.Default.xxx`.

The `.config` file is properly copied to user's computer.

I can't think of any real reason behind this issue. What can possibly prevent the application from finding the relevant settings?

Comment: Is that setings at application level or at user level? In second case is this an update from a previous version? Has version number been updated?

Comment: The settings are user level. And yes, this is an update from a previous version, and the version number has changed.

Comment: The only thing I may imagine (but it's just a guess) is a property that is no longer present in new .config but it was there in old one and for some reason it's still reading old .config (but if version changed it shouldn't be). Did you check what's inside  %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\... folder?

Comment: I deleted the folders relevant to the program in %LocalAppData%.